# How to perform code coverage in C++ using meson?

Tags: c++, code-coverage, ninja, meson-build, catch2

I'm using meson and ninja as build system in my C++ project and I've configured catch2 as testing framework. 
I was wondering how to perform code coverage with the tests that I've written. 
I read this page, https://mesonbuild.com/Unit-tests.html but seems pretty unclear to me, can anybody help?

Comment: install Gcovr then add `-Db_coverage=true` to your meson command line. Is there something specific you dont understand?

Comment: I've installed Gcovr, and run meson build --reconfigure -Db_coverage=true, then in the build folder I run the meson test command, but no coverage file has been generated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use one of coverage related targets: **coverage-text**, **coverage-html**, **coverage-xml** as described [here](https://mesonbuild.com/howtox.html#producing-a-coverage-report). Or just **coverage** that tries all of these if possible:

```
$ ninja coverage -C builddir
```

Results are written to *./builddir/meson-logs* directory.

Note that to produce html coverage reports you need **lcov** and **genhtml** binaries which are installed by **lcov** package.